# Error Undefined index

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo un problema con un formulario: envío las variables por post y lo único que guarda es el nombre de las casillas, y me arroja el error **Undefined Index**. No sé cómo resolver este problema, no tengo ni la menor idea.
Estos son los errores que me marca:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Nombre in  
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Apellido in  
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Correo in  
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Contraseña in
```

Este es mi código:

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <title>Registro</title>
          
        </head>
        
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>
        
        <body>
        
          <p><header><h1>TecnoNeed Registro de Usuario</h1></header></p>
          
                <form enctype="text/plain" method="POST" action="iniciosec.php">
                     Nombre:<input type="text" name="Nombre" minlength="" required=true><br></br>
                     Apellidos:<input type="text" name="Apellidos"  minlength="" required=true><br></br>
                     Correo:<input type="email" name="correo"  minlength="" required=true><br></br>
                     Contraseña:<input type="password" name="Contraseña" minlength="10" required=true><br></br>
        
                     <button  name="button">Ingresar</button>
                     </form>
        
                <a href="Pag_IP/index.html">segir sin registro</a>
        
                    </form>
                </div>
                
        </body>
        
        </html>
```

Este es mi código PHP:

```php
    <?php
    
    
        $conectar=@mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123456789');
    
        if (!$conectar) {
            echo "Error de conexion con el host";
    
                }else{
                    $database='bd_tecnoneed';
             $Base=mysqli_select_db($conectar, $database);
    
            if (!$Base) {
                echo "Base de datos no localizada";
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $Nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
        $Apellidos=$_POST['Apellidos'];
        $Correo=$_POST['Correo'];
        $Contraseña=$_POST['Contraseña'];
        }
        $sql="INSERT INTO registro VALUES('$Nombre','$Apellidos','$Correo','$Contraseña')";
    
        $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);
        if (!$ejecutar) {
            echo "Upps!!! algo salio mal error al enviar los datos";
        }else{
            echo "Tus datos fueron guardados con exito!!!<br><a href='index.html'>Volver<a>";
        }
                
    ?>
```

Comment: Primero el campo de correo lo envías con el nombre "correo" y en el php lo estas recibiendo como "Correo", lo segundo pero deberías verificar si la query te toma la ñ al ingresar los datos, la ñ es del campo contraseña.

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta, pero de mucha importancia: lee sobre inyección SQL en PHP y cómo evitarla. El código compartido contiene vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad y no debería utilizarse en entornos de producción.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que quitar el `enctype="text/plain"` del `<form>`

Los datos solo se envian en la variable `$_POST` si no usas enctype o el enctype es :

- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `multipart/form-data`